# Perl create a formatted table without using an object

Tags: perl

I want to simply output some results in a table without there being any offset problems. Do not worry about the foreach and the output of values that is just pseudocode for clarity.

```
print "\n  ______________________________________________________";
print "\n |                                                      |";
print "\n |                        Title                         |";
print "\n +______________________________________________________+";
print "\n |                          |                           |";
print "\n |          City            |          Size             |";
print "\n |__________________________|___________________________|";

#Sort by highest scores
################################
foreach (city, size)
{
print "\n | (city(value)";
print "| (size(value)";
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: In which Scalar are your Cities/Sizes hold ? Arrays ? Hashes ?

Comment: I like to use the Text::FormatTable module for this sort of thing. A good place to start: http://search.cpan.org/~trey/Text-FormatTable-1.03/lib/Text/FormatTable.pm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use
[`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html)
to overwrite the correct portion of a template line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data = (
  Birmingham  => 1_000_000,
  Bristol     => 430_000,
  Manchester   => 110_000,
);

print "  ______________________________________________________\n";
print " |                                                      |\n";
print " |                        Title                         |\n";
print " +______________________________________________________+\n";

my $template =
      " |                          |                           |\n";
print $template;

while (my ($city, $size) = each %data) {
  my $line = $template;
  substr $line, 12, length $city, $city;
  substr $line, 39, length $size, $size;
  print $line;
}

print " |__________________________|___________________________|\n";
```

**output**

```
  ______________________________________________________
 |                                                      |
 |                        Title                         |
 +______________________________________________________+
 |                          |                           |
 |          Bristol         |          430000           |
 |          Manchester      |          110000           |
 |          Birmingham      |          1000000          |
 |__________________________|___________________________|
```

Answer (score 5):

It's rarely used anymore, but Perl has the built in ability to create these type of [forms](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html).

Basically, you use a specification to state how you want these tables formatted, and where information in these tables will be placed using the `format` statement. Then, you use the Perl `write` statement to write to that format. You can specify headers and footers of your tables too.